# How do I use cmd as a Python console through Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

I have my Sublime Text 3 set up with Python so that when I hit my hotkey for "build", it uses my custom Python build (given below). What it does is build/run the code through the python compiler via cmd (command prompt). Thus I get my outputs in the windows cmd.

Problem is, after the program terminates I am left with a blank cmd window. What I want is for it to stay in interactive Python mode (so that I can print out variables that are in the memory, etc.). How could I achieve this?

The custom Python+cmd build:

```
{


"cmd": ["mingw32-g++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"],
"path": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\",

"variants": [

    {   
        "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
        "shell": true,
        "name": "Run"
    }
            ]
}
```

Comment: You probably want to run the Python IDE from subl, not a standard cmd+python shell. Since python.exe is just ment to run the code and then drop to the shell again. Where as the IDE with say a import statement would carry out the code and drop back to the IDE shell. For instance, check if Python IDLE can be started with a `import your_script` row. That way, your code would hopefully get executed, and you'd be left with a `>>>` prompt. But you won't achieve this with `/k` in cmd.exe, it's not designed to let you stay in a "python environment", it will just execute python.exe and drop to cmd.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm failing to pass the argument to python.exe though. Multiple arguments to be precise (import sys and also a command to add my script folder to the search path, so that import my_script works).

Comment: The console window is not the CMD *shell* and has nothing to do with it. Run python.exe directly and it will allocate its own console. Use the `-i` command-line option to have it drop into interactive mode after it executes the script.

Comment: @eryksun I have set the command to "cmd": ["D:\\Python36\\python.exe", "-i", "$file"] but after it runs the program all it does is give me ">>>" which are plain text (i.e. no interactivity).

Comment: You should be able to type into the console, unless Sublime executes Python with stdin redirected. In that case try using CMD's `start` command to force running Python with a new console: `"cmd": ["start", "Sublime Python Shell", "D:\\Python36\\python.exe", "-i", "$file"]` plus `"shell": true`. Setting the console window title to "Sublime Python Shell" allows the console settings for just this window to be saved under "HKCU\Console\Sublime Python Shell", or whatever title you use.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you very much!